# integrating slightly complicated expression which includes Abs

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have been waiting for *Mathematica* to give me something for the following integral, errors welcome, but it has been "running" for almost 30 minutes now.

```
     h[s_] := If[1 < s, 1, 0]
     Integrate[
              Abs[1/(b1^2 + b2^2)
               2 E^(-b1 s) ((a1 b1 + a2 b2) E^(
              b1 s) - (a1 b1 + a2 b2) Cos[b2 s] + (-a2 b1 + a1 b2) Sin[
               b2 s]) - h[s]],  {s, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> b1 > 0]
```

Is there a way to simplify this so that *Mathematica* would not take this long, or is this an entirely lost case?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Actually you can get rid of the function h by breaking the Integral to two, one in the range $(0,1)$ and one in the range $(1,\infty)$. Now if you have more information about the constants in order to get rid of the `Abs` things might get better.

Comment: Also it might be better instead of `h` to use `UnitStep[s-1]`.

Comment: No other assumptions on your other parameters? Note that `h[s]` is expressible as `Boole[1 < s]`.

Comment: I changed h to unitstep[s-1], running now, will let you know  @Spawn1701D

Comment: no other assumptions @J.M., I just need b1 to be positive for convergence.

Comment: I gave up. Now, I am trying to break up into integral two as you have suggested, hope it works. @Spawn1701D

Comment: I am afraid that if you don't get rid of the `Abs` things will be difficult.

Comment: integrating in two pieces didnt work either @Spawn1701D

Comment: Actually, you need more than $b_1\gt 0$: you also must require $2(a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2) = b_1^2 + b_2^2$ to avoid divergence as $s\to \infty$.  Generically, this "doesn't happen" because it describes a hypersurface (of zero measure) in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided $2(a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2) = b_1^2 + b_2^2$, there exists a closed-form solution that *Mathematica* can obtain quickly.  But you have to do a little analysis along the way :-).

**I won't carry out the full solution, but will show how to do the difficult part.**  The motivation for the first step is recognizing that expressions like $b_1^2+b_2^2$, $a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2$, etc., have geometric meanings that can be expressed in terms of the lengths of the vectors $(a_1, a_2)$ and $(b_1, b_2)$ and the angles between them.  Accordingly, let's introduce polar coordinates for both:

```
{a1, a2} = a {Cos[\[Alpha]], Sin[\[Alpha]]};
{b1, b2} = b {Cos[\[Beta]], Sin[\[Beta]]};
```

Remember, for future use, that $a\ge 0$ and $b \ge 0$.

Applying `FullSimplify` to the integrand yields an expression similar to this one, in which I have manually distributed the exponentials into the numerator:

$$\frac{ \left|2 a e^{-\Re(b s \cos (\beta ))}\cos (\alpha -\beta -b s \sin (\beta ))+ (b h(s)-2 a \cos (\alpha -\beta ))\right|}{|b|}.$$

**For the integral to converge, the first term must decay**--implying $b\cos(\beta)\gt 0$--and the second term simply cannot be present for arbitrarily large $s$.  For such values, $h(s)=1$.  We must therefore enforce

$$b - 2 a \cos(\alpha-\beta) = 0.$$

This is equivalent to the condition stated at the beginning of this answer:

```
(-2 (a1 b1 + a2 b2) + ( b1^2 + b2^2))/b // FullSimplify
```

> $$b-2 a \text{Cos}[\alpha -\beta]$$

When this condition holds, and remembering $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative, the integrand is

$$\frac{2 a e^{-b s \cos (\beta )} |\cos (\alpha -\beta -b s \sin (\beta ))|}{b}$$

**To simplify this further, let's re-parameterize it.**  It looks like it's in the form of a constant times and exponential times a cosine. Here are the new parameters that will make it so:

```
rules = {c -> 2 a / b, k -> Cot[\[Beta]], u -> b Sin[\[Beta]], \[Gamma] -> (\[Alpha] - \[Beta])};
```

As a check, the calculation

```
c Exp[-k u s] Abs[Cos[\[Gamma] - u s]] /. rules  // TraditionalForm
```

reproduces the previous formula.

Now for the analysis.  First, it is clear that a **change of variable** from `s` to `u s` will help: it eliminates one free parameter `u` (at the cost merely of dividing the answer by $u$ afterwards).  Some care will be needed to distinguish the three cases $u \lt 0$, $u=0$, and $u \gt 0$.  I will illustrate the case $u \gt 0$.  (The case $u \lt 0$ is almost the same and $u = 0$ is easy because the cosine disappears.)  Let's illustrate:

```
With[{k = 1/8, g = 2}, 
 base = Plot[Exp[-k s] Cos[g + s], {s, 0, 20}, Filling -> Axis, 
  FillingStyle -> {RGBColor[.9, .6, .6], RGBColor[.6, .6, .9]}, PlotRange -> Full]];
first = Plot[Exp[-k s] Cos[g + s], {s, 0, 2 \[Pi] - \[Pi]/2 - u}, 
   Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> GrayLevel[0.9]]];
Show[base, first]]
```

[image: Plot]

Here I have plotted the argument *without the absolute value.*  With the absolute value, we are requesting the total (unsigned) area of the gray, red, and blue parts.  **The strategy is to compute this area in three pieces according to the colors.**

We therefore break the argument of the absolute value into its positive and negative parts.  To find out where it is positive--if it's not plainly obvious already--apply `Reduce`:

```
Reduce[Cos[\[Gamma] - s] >= 0 , s, Reals]
```

> $C[1]\in \text{Integers}\&\&\frac{1}{2} (-\pi +2 \gamma +4 \pi  C[1])\leq s\leq \frac{1}{2} (\pi +2 \gamma +4 \pi  C[1])$

This is a countable set of regions indexed by the integer `C[1]`.  Let's perform the integration over a single such region and, afterwards, replace the cosines with $1$ and the sines with $0$:

```
Integrate[
  Exp[-k s] Cos[\[Gamma] - s], 
    {s, 1/2 (-\[Pi] + 2 \[Gamma] + 4 \[Pi] C[1]), 1/2 (\[Pi] + 2 \[Gamma] + 4 \[Pi] C[1])}, 
  Assumptions ->  C[1] \[Element] Integers && k > 0 && \[Gamma] \[Element] Reals] 
/. {Cos[2 \[Pi] C[1]] -> 1, Sin[2 \[Pi] C[1]] -> 0, C[1] -> n}
```

> $$\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2} k (\pi +4 n \pi +2 \gamma )} \left(1+e^{k \pi }\right)}{1+k^2}$$

The same treatment of the regions where the integrand is the absolute value of a negative number yields

> $$\frac{e^{-k \left(\left(\frac{3}{2}+2 n\right) \pi +\gamma \right)} \left(1+e^{k \pi }\right)}{1+k^2}$$

It remains now only to

1. Integrate over the first partial period of $\cos(\gamma - s)$ (the gray lobe in the plot) which has a closed form value that `Integrate` will handily produce,
2. Add to that the sum of the preceding values starting at an appropriate initial value of $n$ (indexing precisely the red and blue lobes in the plot).

At this juncture I will only demonstrate that **the sum has a closed form** (it is, in fact, merely a geometric series) and leave it to interested (or more dedicated) readers to determine where to start the summation.

```
Sum[(E^(-(1/2) k (\[Pi] + 4 n \[Pi] + 2 \[Gamma])) (1 + E^(k \[Pi])))/(1 + k^2)
  + (E^(-k ((3/2 + 2 n) \[Pi] + \[Gamma])) (1 + E^(k \[Pi])))/(1 + k^2), 
  {n, 1, Infinity}] // FullSimplify
```

> $$\frac{e^{-2 k (\pi +\gamma )} \left(e^{k \left(\frac{3 \pi }{2}+\gamma \right)}+e^{\frac{1}{2} k (\pi +2 \gamma )}\right)}{\left(-1+e^{k \pi }\right) \left(1+k^2\right)}$$

To account for the change of variable we must divide this by $u$ and then back-substitute:

```
%/u /. rules
```

> $$\frac{e^{-2 (\pi +\alpha -\beta ) \text{Cot}[\beta ]} \left(e^{\frac{1}{2} (\pi +2 (\alpha -\beta )) \text{Cot}[\beta ]}+e^{\left(\frac{3 \pi }{2}+\alpha -\beta \right) \text{Cot}[\beta ]}\right) \text{Csc}[\beta ]}{b \left(-1+e^{\pi  \text{Cot}[\beta ]}\right) \left(1+\text{Cot}[\beta ]^2\right)}$$

One may go further and re-express this in terms of the $a_i$ and $b_i$, but this is far enough.

Comment: big +1 for both patience and exposition!

Comment: @whuber, I was not expecting such a complete response. Even though I am not sure if I'll be able to understand all of it considering my novice mathematica skills, I want to say : eternal thanks. This is just amazing.

Answer (score 3):

This integral diverges; you can see that by looking at the behaviour of the integrand for real values of the parameters.

Compile the integrand:

```
h[s_] := UnitStep[s - 1];
g = Compile[{{a1, _Real}, {a2, _Real}, {b1, _Real}, {b2, _Real}, {s,_Real}},
       Abs[1/(b1^2 + b2^2) 2 E^(-b1 s) ((a1 b1 + a2 b2) E^(b1 s) - (a1 b1 + 
          a2 b2) Cos[b2 s] + (-a2 b1 + a1 b2) Sin[b2 s]) - h[s]], 
  CompilationTarget -> "C"
  ];
```

And then `Plot` it for (arbitrary) ranges of your `a1, a2, b1, b2`:

```
Manipulate[
     Plot[g[a1, a2, b1, b2, s], {s, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All], 
 {a1, -5, 5}, {a2, -5, 5}, {b2, -5, 5}, {b1, 0, 5}]
```

for large `s` it asymptotically reaches a non-zero value:

[image: asymptotic divergence]

So you need to impose some other constraint if you want this to converge.

**----EDIT----**

So given the additional constraint $ \frac{b_1^2 +b_2^2}{2} = a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 $ that @whuber spotted, your integrand becomes:

```
Abs[1/(b1^2 + 
   b2^2) 2 E^(-b1 s) ((a1 b1 + a2 b2) E^(b1 s) - (a1 b1 + 
     a2 b2) Cos[b2 s] + (-a2 b1 + a1 b2) Sin[b2 s]) - h[s]] /. (b1^2 + b2^2) -> 2 ( a1*b1 + a2*b2)

(*out*)
Abs[(E^(-b1 s) ((a1 b1 + a2 b2) E^(
  b1 s) - (a1 b1 + a2 b2) Cos[b2 s] + (-a2 b1 + a1 b2) Sin[b2 s]))/(a1 b1 + a2 b2) 
  - UnitStep[-1 + s]]
```

Now, integrating this will be hard: the integral oscillates a lot if $ |b_2|>>1 $ and it gets dampened very slowly if $b_1<<1.$ I don't think it has an analytic solution. Numerically you may get a reasonable result for a range of parameters with this:

```
intg[a1_?NumberQ, a2_?NumberQ, b1_?NumberQ /; (b1 > 0), b2_?NumberQ] :=
  NIntegrate[
  Abs[(E^(-b1 s) ((a1 b1 + a2 b2) E^(
        b1 s) - (a1 b1 + a2 b2) Cos[b2 s] + (-a2 b1 + a1 b2) Sin[
         b2 s]))/(a1 b1 + a2 b2) - UnitStep[-1 + s]]
  , {s, 0, Infinity}, 
  Method -> {"DoubleExponentialOscillatory", 
    "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, WorkingPrecision -> 10, 
  MinRecursion -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 100, AccuracyGoal -> 8]
```

(which is an adapted example from [the NIntegrate Integration Strategies](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#775797877)) but, as I said, this breaks down around $  b_1 \sim .01 $ and/or $ b_2 \sim 100 $ or more, i.e.

```
intg[23, 3, .001, .12]

(*out*)
NIntegrate::slwcon: 
  Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the 
     integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small. >>
4622.972541
```

For these, you'd need to do something more exotic like integrate period by period and see if the series of integrals converges or other such things. Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: Actually, this integral *does* converge for certain values of the $a_i$ and $b_i$. Your observation is useful in that it indicates *Mathematica* may be working hard to characterize when the integral is convergent.

Comment: @whuber, yes, I completely agree. It's just the OP implied in a comment that $ b_1>0 $ is a sufficient condition for this to converge whereas clearly it isn't.

Comment: (+1) I just noticed that comment and added a response describing a (minimal) extra condition that is needed. Imposing it still leaves a difficult-to-evaluate integrand of the form $\exp(-k s)|\cos(u + s)| ds$.

Comment: @whuber, you are absolutely right. I added the line to the top 
     2 (a1*b1 + a2*b2) == b1^2 + b2^2
yet, it has been 15 minutes, and it says "Running"